# Acrescentar 0 a esquerda em um ArrayList <Integer>

Tags: java

Olá, esse código devolve 6 valores entre 1 e 60 sem repetir e em ordem. Mas para os números menores que 10 eu gostaria de acrescentar 0 antes tipo: 01,02...10.
Ja tentei usar String.format() mas dá erro na hora de compilar.

Agradeço.

```
private static String sortear() {
    Set<Integer> numberset = new HashSet<>();
    Random random = new Random();

    while (numberset.size() < 6) {
        numberset.add((random.nextInt(60) + 1));
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> jogo = new ArrayList<>(numberset);
    Collections.sort(jogo);


    String vetor = Arrays.toString(jogo.toArray());

    return vetor;



}
```

Comment: Esta parte do código não tem nada a ver com o erro que você descreve na pergunta. A parte onde dá o erro você não postou. Poste-a pra gente ver onde está o erro e como podemos ajudar. E mostre o erro também, quanto mais informações úteis der mais tem chances de ajudarmos.

Comment: É que estou fazendo pelo Android Studio, quando acrescento no final do código :
return String.format( Formato.JOGO, vetor);

O erro é este:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format java.util.ArrayList arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar dessa forma também,
Ao invés de utilizar tudo como "Integer" já começar trabalhando com "String".
Mas o pulo do gato está mesmo no comando: `String.format("%02d", NumeroQueVoceQuerFormatar)`.

```
private static String sortear() {

        Set<String> numberset = new HashSet<>();

        Random random = new Random();

        while (numberset.size() < 6) {
            String numero = String.format("%02d", (random.nextInt(60) + 1));
            numberset.add(numero);
        }

        ArrayList<String> jogo = new ArrayList<>(numberset);
        Collections.sort(jogo);

        String vetor = Arrays.toString(jogo.toArray());

        return vetor;
    }
```

Esse foi o resultado: `[08, 21, 25, 33, 34, 48]`

Comment: Muito obrigado Richard, funcionou exatamente como queria

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class Teste {
    private static final Random RND = new Random();

    private static String comZero(int x) {
        return (x < 10 ? "0" : "") + x;
    }

    private static String sortear() {
        SortedSet<Integer> numberset = new TreeSet<>();
        while (numberset.size() < 6) {
            numberset.add((RND.nextInt(60) + 1));
        }
        return numberset.stream().map(Teste::comZero).collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();
    }
}
```

Testei isso com esse código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sortear());
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
[01, 28, 34, 46, 48, 49]
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/S4znXw)

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, testei o do Richard Willian antes e funcionou como eu queria, testei esse que me enviou e também funcionou, mto obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode criar um array de string só para tratar esse retorno e usar o metodo format da string, dessa forma:

```
private static String sortear() {
    Set<Integer> numberset = new HashSet<>();
    Random random = new Random();

    while (numberset.size() < 6) {
        numberset.add((random.nextInt(60) + 1));
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> jogo = new ArrayList<>(numberset);
    Collections.sort(jogo);

    List<String> jogoString = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Integer num : jogo) {
        //%02d diz que vc quer uma string com tamanho de 2 digitos
        jogoString.add(String.format("%02d", num));
    }


    String vetor = Arrays.toString(jogoString.toArray());

    return vetor;

}
```

Comment: Testei aqui, mas não funcionou para mim, o do Richard Willian resolveu a minha questão, agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

> Mas para os números menores que 10 eu gostaria de acrescentar 0 antes
>   tipo: 01,02...10.

Apenas com `String.format("%02d", 3);` já resolve essa formatação que você precisa.

Comment: tentei assim, mas dá o seguinte erro:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format java.util.ArrayList arguments

Comment: Posta a parte que dá o erro.

Comment: Eu segui a orientação do Richard Willian, e solucionou o problema. Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: @AntonioSantos, creio que para dar esse erro, ele tenha colocado o `Array` já convertido em `String` dentro do método, no lugar do `3`.
`String.format("%02d", ArrayList.toString());`
Por isso deve ter dado o erro.